# Type hinting in Python, for the case where there's no single superclass

Tags: python, type-hinting

In sklearn, there are several different scaler classes , such as `MinMaxScaler`, or `StandardScaler`, which inherit from `OneToOneFeatureMixin`, `TransformerMixin`, `BaseEstimator`.

My FeatureEngineering class receives a scaler. However, I would like to type hint it, instead of having to specify the scaler class, as is below.

```
class FeatureEngineering(ABC):
    def __init__(self, dataframe:pd.DataFrame, scaler:MinMaxScaler | None = None):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        self.scaler = scaler
```

I thought of creating a new class, called `GeneralScaler`, and make it inherit from all the sklearn superclasses, or using a Union (typing) operator. However, I have a feeling this shouldn't be done...

1. Is there a way to properly type hint for this?
2. Does Python allow the creation of specific type for this case? How?

Comment: Do these scalers all have the same interface?

Comment: @Mark, there's a method called partial_fit, which exists only in some scalers, but the method I want to use (for now) exists in all, with the same interface.

Comment: You can define a Protocol class that specifies the parts you care about that all the unrelated classes have in common https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html

Comment: You could potentially make answering your question easier for other, if you include _links_ to the relevant lines of source code for those `sklearn` classes.

Comment: i think you want an intersection type, but those aren't in python yet. Protocol is indeed one option

Comment: @Anentropic Yes, I think Protocol will have to do it. Thanks ;)